# Background service that spawns other services/tasks

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

i'm trying to wrap my head around Service/Task in javafx and how to handle nesting them together. My app is a simple rss downloader. It downloads multiple feeds, and it also downloads the html inside each feed item's `<link>`. I want the entire download process to be async (to keep the GUI from freezing), as well as each rss feed download and each html download. I want the process to look something like this.

```
Application thread.
|
|
|--------Download process start(Service)
|       |
|       |
|       |----RSS download start(Service)
|       |    |(30+ Tasks that each download an individual feed.
|       |----RSS download end
|       |
|       |
|       |----HTML download start(Service)
|       |    |(100+ Tasks that each download an individual HTML page.
|       |----HTML download end
|       |
|       |
|--------Download process end.
|
|
```

My Code. downloadStart() kicks off the `Downloader` Service.

```
    @Override 
    public void downloadStart(List<Channel> channels) {
        Downloader downloader = new Downloader(channels);
        downloader.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                List<Article> result = (List<Article>)t.getSource().getValue();
                display.printToOutput("Completed download process : " + result.size());
            }
        });
        downloader.start();
    }
```

The `Downloader` class.

```
public class Downloader extends Service<List<Article>> {

List<Channel> channels;

public Downloader(List<Channel> channels){
    this.channels = channels;
}

public void downloadRSS() {
    for(Channel channel : channels){
        RSSDownloadService<List<Article>> downloader = new RSSDownloadService<List<Article>>(channel);
        downloader.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                List<Article> result = (List<Article>)t.getSource().getValue();
                downloadHTML(result);
            }
        });
        downloader.start();
    }
}

private void downloadHTML(List<Article> articles){
    HTMLDownloadService<List<Article>> downloader = new HTMLDownloadService<List<Article>>(articles);
    downloader.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            List<Article> result = (List<Article>)t.getSource().getValue();
            //how do i tell the Downloader service to return this result?
        }
    });
    downloader.start();
}

@Override
protected Task<List<Article>> createTask() {
    return new Task<List<Article>>() {
        protected List<Article> call() {
            downloadRSS();
            //i can't return anything until downloadHTML() finishes!!
        }
    };
}

}
```

The Problem: After starting the Downloader service, it's `createTask()` method calls `downloadRSS()` and expects a return value. However, `downloadRSS()` method doesn't return anything, it starts `RSSDownloadService`. When `RSSDownloadService` succeeds, it calls downloadHTML(), which starts `HTMLDownloadService`. Finally, when that succeeds, i want to end the entire `Downloader` service and return the `List` of articles. I'm not sure how to proceed.

The `RSSDownloadService` and `HTMLDownloadService` work just fine. They were simple for me to implement because they call one method with a return value. However the `DownloaderService' somehow needs to wait for the 2 services to complete, and return the 2nd services succeed value.

Comment: Does `HTMLDownloadService` need to start after `RSSDownloadService` has completed ?

Comment: Yes. I need to get the URL's from the RSS.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the end result should be and how it relates to the return values of the individual downloads, i.e. `HTMLDownloadService` and `RSSDownloadService`. Both of these result in a `List<Article>`.  Is the idea that each `RSSDownloadService` returns a list which is the concatenation of all the `Article`s returned by the `HTMLDownloadService`s it spawns?

Comment: `RSSDownloadService` returns a list of `Article` objects. An `Article` contains stuff from the RSS, like title, publication date, link. However, it does not contain the full article content. Which is why the RSS passes the incomplete `Article` List to the `HTMLDownloadService`, which loops over the list, goes to each URL it finds, and downloads the HTML. The end result is a List of `Article` objects, with the full HTML content. If i returned the List before `HTMLDownloadService`, it would contain everything from the RSS, except the full HTML content.

Comment: Yes James, that is the general Idea i think. Basically, i want to start the process with `downloadRSS`, and return the value of `HTMLDownloadService` success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `downloadRSS()` to return a `List<Article>` which contains all the `Article`s from all the lists returned by the `HTMLDownloadService`s it spawns.

I think the following does what you want:

```
public List<Article> downloadRSS() {

    List<Article> mainList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(channels.size());

    for(Channel channel : channels){
        RSSDownloadService<List<Article>> downloader = new RSSDownloadService<List<Article>>(channel);
        downloader.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                List<Article> result = (List<Article>)t.getSource().getValue();
                downloadHTML(result, mainList, latch);
            }
        });
        downloader.setOnFailed(t -> {
            // handle error if neccessary...
            latch.countDown();
        });
        downloader.start();
    }
    latch.await();
    // return a regular list, don't need the overhead of synchronization any more:
    return new ArrayList<>(mainList);
}

private void downloadHTML(List<Article> articles, List<Article> mainList, CountDownLatch latch){
    HTMLDownloadService<List<Article>> downloader = new HTMLDownloadService<List<Article>>(articles);
    downloader.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            List<Article> result = (List<Article>)t.getSource().getValue();
            mainList.addAll(result);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    downloader.setOnFailed(t -> {
        // handle error if needed...
        latch.countDown();
    });
    downloader.start();
}

@Override
protected Task<List<Article>> createTask() {
    return new Task<List<Article>>() {
        protected List<Article> call() {
            return downloadRSS();
        }
    };
}
```

Here's perhaps a better approach, using Java 8 streams and built-in parallelization to manage most of the threading:

```
public class Downloader extends Task<List<Article>> {

    private final List<Channel> channels ;

    public Downloader(List<Channel> channels) {
        this.channels = channels ;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> call() throws Exception {
        return channels.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(channel -> getRssList(channel).parallelStream())
            .flatMap(rss -> getHtmlList(rss).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<Article> getRssList(Channel channel) {
        // this runs in its own thread, return List<Article> for given channel
    }

    private List<Article> getHtmlList(Article rss) {
        // this runs in its own thread, return List<Article> for given rss
    }
}
```

And then all you need in the ui is:

```
List<Channel> channels = ... ;
Downloader downloader = new Downloader(channels);
downloader.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    List<Article> articles = downloader.getValue();
    // update UI with articles...
});
Thread t = new Thread(downloader);
t.setDaemon(true) ; // will not prevent application exit...
t.start();
```

Comment: Thanks James, i'll try this out, i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It doesn't quite feel right, because there's more being done on the FX Application thread (in the `onSucceeded` handlers) than really need to happen there. You might refactor it so that the "subtasks" just directly add results to the main list, and count the latch down accordingly, instead of returning a value that is processed on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Are you saying that the `onSucceeded` handlers are happening in Application thread, even though they're inside the `Downloader` Service?

Comment: Updated with a Java 8 version using a single task and Streams.

Comment: Darn, i was in the middle of testing your first answer. I'm not familiar at all with Java 8 Stream API, so your updated answer looks a bit funky to me, but i'm willing to give it a try. Could you perhaps add what it would look like if i had a method `foo(List<Article> list)` (returns a modified List<Article>), in between `getRssList` and `getHtmlList`, in the syntax of Java 8? So `getRssList` would pass the list to `foo`, which would modify it, then `foo` would pass the list to `getHtmlList`.

Comment: You would just replace `flatMap(rss -> getHtmlList(rss).stream())` with `flatMap(rss -> { foo(rss); return getHtmlList(rss).stream();})`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Everything works, thanks a bunch. Java 8 streams are like magic, they reduced my lines of code by 75%